# window decoration missing after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, catalyst, window-decoration

A few seconds after login my window decorations disappear and I have a black desktop background.

I installed the latest catalyst drivers. 13.4. I have an HD7880.

I Tried:

> gtk-window-decorator --replace
>
> unity --reset
>
> reinstalling drivers.

how to debug / fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running with a Radeon HD 6400M, and 13.04 seems to really not like the updated graphics drivers (or at least, that's the conclusion I've come to). After installing them I had exactly the same issue.

For me, the following worked:

`sudo apt-get purge fglrx`

followed by (possibly after a reboot, I can't quite remember. Probably do one just to be sure)

`gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins`

The latter command seemed to take quite a long time to run, but once it had everything worked fine thereafter. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to reboot after installing or removing the proprietary drivers (ati and nvidia) as they are loaded in the initrd